# Search box with clickable keywords?

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, lean-ux, microinteractions

I'm working on a search box in which the user will be entering keywords that can be clicked/interacted with.
For example, say, a user types in "Fender Guitar", the words "Fender" and "Guitar" will be clickable and will display its metadata when clicked.
Is there an existing example of such a pattern? I'm pretty sure I've seen it somewhere before but can't remember one right now. 
What would be a good way to tell the user that the entered word is clickable? Are [chips](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#action-chips) good for this?

Comment: "jQuery tag input" should lead you to some useful results

Comment: can you provide a user flow, why is a user click on key words they have entered in a text input field?

Answer (score 1):

[Filter chips](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#filter-chips) are quite commonly used but you could add an indicator that they are clickable, e.g. underlining the link or including an icon that tells the user that clicking on the chip will bring up a tooltip containing more information.